# split() works differently with more than one whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am trying to replace the first letter of every word in a string to uppercase and got it working by splitting the string then mapping through each word as follows:

```
var S = 'hello world';
var x = S.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ');

console.log(x);
```

### BUT:

If the string contains more than one white-space as follows, I get an error **`Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`**.

```
var S = 'hello   world';
var x = S.toLowerCase().split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ');

console.log(x);
```

---

I tried adding a `+` to .split(' ') and .join(' ') as recommended in past stackoverflow threads as follows but doing that only capitalises the first letter of the first word instead:

```
var S = 'hello    world';
var x = S.toLowerCase().split(' +').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' +');

console.log(x); // returns 'Hello    world'
```

---

What would be the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a RegExp to replace just the 1st character of each word with an upper case version:

```js
var S = 'hello   world';
var x = S.toLowerCase().replace(/\b\w/g, (m) => m.toUpperCase());

console.log(x);
```

If you still want to use `String.split()`, use RegExp, and split the array by `\s+` (a sequence of spaces - space, tab, etc...):

```js
var S = 'hello   world';
var x = S.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ');

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first should remove duplicate whitespaces with a regex.

```
var S = 'hello    world';
var x = S.replace(/  +/g, ' ').toLowerCase().split(' ').map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1)).join(' ');
```

But if you want to keep those spaces you might want to use

```
var S = 'hello    world';
var x = S.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is because you're accessing the first character of an empty string, the following gives the same result:

```
word = ''
word[0].toUppercase() ...
```

you have to handle the case when string is empty

```
word === '' ? word : word[0].toUppercase() ...
```

Comment: That would cause every letter of the word to capitalise instead of just the first letter Nahuel.

Comment: ok but you missed to handle the case where the string is empty

Comment: are you interrested to keep multiple spaces otherwise you can use `.split(/ +/g)` to use multiple space as delimiter

Comment: I dont understand. What do you mean?

Comment: about my comments, what i meant is that regex passed to split is used to find the next separator as it is already repeated the `g` modifier after regexp is not used `.split(/ +/)` should be sufficient